# How to add elements in Binary search tree iteratively?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, binary-tree

```
   public void Insert(int value)
    {
        if (value < Data)
        {
            if (LeftNode == null)
            {
                LeftNode = new TreeNode(value);
            }
            else
            {
                LeftNode.Insert(value);
            }
        }
        else if (value > Data)
        {
            if (RightNode == null)
            {
                RightNode = new TreeNode(value);
            }
            else
            {
                RightNode.Insert(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote method to add element in BST recursively, It checks for value to add less than or greater than and add it in its proper place, but I want to know how iterative method works? I need iterative add method for my BST.

Comment: yes, non recursive method, actually I am reading data from a text file containing about 10000 words, when I add them to BST, it gives me STACKOVERFLOW EXCEPTION. I think recursive method is the problem.

Comment: What has he tried? He has put down his method...

Comment: @Aki: Is the input file sorted? If so, you are building a linked list instead of a binary tree. Every element would be added to the right hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a implementation in Java at wikipedia, what is very similar C# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

We start at root:

```
Node root = m_root;
    while (root != null) {
```

then look if the value is less os greater than root.

```
if (data < root.getData()) {
```

Now we know if we need to traverse at left or right. The logic at left and right are the same. We look if the slot is empty and if it is, we put the value at that slot.

```
if (root.getLeft() == null) {
    root.setLeft(new TreeNode(data, null, null));
    return;
}
```

If the slot contains a value, then we set that slot as root and continue the process.

```
} else {
    root = root.getLeft();
}
```

Comment: The question is about how it works, not asking for an implementation.

Comment: The code is very simple, explain that is likely explain what each line do, but I can do it for you

Answer (score 9):

Ok, here's an iterative version of your algorithm:

```
public void Insert(int value)
{
    TreeNode current = this;
    while (current != null)
    {
        if(current.Data < value)
            if(current.LeftNode == null)
            { current.LeftNode = new TreeNode(value); break; }
            else current = current.LeftNode;
        else
            if(current.RightNode == null)
            { current.RightNode = new TreeNode(value); break; }
            else current = current.RightNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning: generally a node in BST should have lower keys in the its left subtree, and higher in the right. However, this algorithm works the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

An iterative method is one that will repeat.

Iterative method implies it will be called repeatedly.
Recursion implies the method will call itself n times, where n > 0.

Searching a binary search tree is done using a method which calls itself (recursive) until it finds the end of a branch.

To do an insert, a search is executed to find the correct place to place the node.

Comment: Russel, I understand that a iterative method uses a loop instead of calling itself. Any method that works with recursion, theoretically can be done using a loop, but recursion is much more easy e clean. The best of two worlds is tail recursion

Comment: @Fujiy A loop inside a method is an iterative expression inside a method.  An iterative method is one that is part of a loop itself.